# Chef Knife Commands 404 Not Found

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm trying to use chef, I followed all the steps provided by them to "Install and configure Chef server using your hardware"

I've run the following commands from the workstation

```
knife SSL check
```

Output

> Connecting to host my_server:443
>   Successfully verified certificates from `my_server'

However when I use the following command

```
knife client list
```

Output:

> ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found

What is going on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found what is the root cause of my error, the chef_server_url must has the organization's name at the end of the URL.

chef_server_url   'https://my_server:443/organizations/my_organization_name'

I added the org name and it solved my issue(404 not found)

Comment: In Chef 15, I set `chef_server_url` (as well as `client_name`) using the command `knife configure`. The values will be stored at `/home/$USER/.chef/credentials`. I would recommend to verify the values in the file (I had made a typo and this saved me!)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared your `knife.rb` file in order to be more specific (in knife.rb you have to indicate your `client_key`,`validation_client_name`, `validation_key` etc), in general you don't have any registered chef-clients neither bootstrapped machines nor even local one. Here is the document about how to [create your client](https://docs.chef.io/knife_client.html#create). Here you might have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259567/chef-server-return-404-for-all-knife-and-chef-client-request) as well.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, I found what is the root cause of my error, the chef_server _url must has the organization at the end of the URL, chef_server_url          'https://my_server:443/organizations/my_organization_name'. I added the org name and it solved my issues(404 not found)